# Program to generate a new table in MySQL database everytime the program is run

Tags: java, mysql

My program is not able to generate a new name for the table evertime the program s run as a result of which it not being created. here is my code :-

```
package org.java.myfirstapp;

import java.sql.*;



public class ConnectForm {



    public void createFormData(String name,String num){
        Connection con=null;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/formdata", "root", null);
            try{
                int no=1,no1 = 0;
                do{Statement st=con.createStatement();
                    no1=no;

                int x;
                x= st.executeUpdate("create table form"+no+" (Product varchar(20),Fields varchar(20))");


                if(x==0){ 

                st.executeUpdate("insert into form"+no+" values ('"+name+"','"+num+"')");
                }
                else {
                    no++;}


                }while(no1<no);
            }
            catch(SQLException e1){

                System.err.println("Error code:"+e1.getMessage());}

        }
            catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, now please go and read the [FAQ]

Comment: Is this Jeopardy? Should we now phrase a question?

Comment: @Vash Eclipse is not being able to find java.util.Random although i find it in my Java SDK

Comment: @BrianAgnew I get an error saying 'form1' is already created.

Comment: @user1481851, Please edit your question with those two comments.

Answer (score 0):

> Eclipse is not being able to find java.util.Random although i find it in my Java SDK

In the example that you have presented you do not use the class 'java.util.Random', but this type of error indicate that you are probably missing the import or the build path is not set correctly.

[What import are ?](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html)
[What is build path ?](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm)

About the second issue

> form1' is already created

This probably stand for that table was already created by your application on database using this line of code.

`t.executeUpdate("create table form"+no+" (Product varchar(20),Fields varchar(20)`

Comment: yes but shouldn't the control go from the if to the else block since the condition in the if statement won't be true? Then a new name will be assigned to the table i.e form2

Comment: First of all you should not use executeUpdate for DDL. Second is thay you fist execute `create` then you have the if.

Comment: okay so what is the alternative to using executeUpdate for DDL? Also thanks a lot for your help and patience. I am new at this so this is really helpful. Also even if i execute the create statement in the condition for 'if' and compare its value to zero the same error occurs.

Comment: I think that at this point you should invest your time in some tutorial. Here you have lot of examples http://www.java2s.com/